# Building a new Excel sheet from queries on existing sheets

Tags: vba, excel

This code runs a number of queries on various sheets, copies the table values to new sheets for manipulation such as sorting and summing, and finally builds a template sheet from the newly manipulated results.  In doing so I find there is a lot of redundant code which I think could be streamlined but I'm not sure.

I'm self taught and hoping that people with more experience and knowledge can look over the following code and provide me with some pointers to optimize and streamline the process. Things such as 'rather than rebuild the arrays why don't you create global arrays', or 'you're really not accomplishing anything with that lastRow function'...

```
Sub Refresh() 'Clear previous queries and results sets
    Dim DataSh, ResultsSh As Worksheet

    'Show wait screen
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Refresh the query sheets
    For Each DataSh In Sheets(Array("DP-CustomerDates", "DP-FirstDeliveries", "DP-SalesW1", "DP-SalesW2", _
     "DP-SalesW3", "DP-SalesW4", "DP-SalesW5", "DP-SalesW6", "DP-SalesW7", "DP-SalesW8", "DP-SalesW9", _
      "DP-SalesW10", "DP-SalesW11", "DP-SalesW12", "DP-SalesW13", "DP-SalesW14", "DP-SalesW15"))
        DataSh.Select
        Rows.Hidden = False
            With ActiveSheet
                .Rows("2:" & .Rows.Count).Select
                Selection.ClearContents
            End With
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Next

    'Remove previous results
    For Each ResultsSh In Sheets(Array("CustomerDates", "FirstDeliveries", "SalesW1", "SalesW2", _
     "SalesW3", "SalesW4", "SalesW5", "SalesW6", "SalesW7", "SalesW8", "SalesW9", "SalesW10", _
      "SalesW11", "SalesW12", "SalesW13", "SalesW14", "SalesW15"))
        ResultsSh.Select
        'Clear old result set from array
        Rows.Hidden = False
        With ActiveSheet
            .Columns("A:AX").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        End With
        'Selection.RemoveSubtotal
        Range("A1").Select
    Next

    'Remove previous template results
    Worksheets("Commission Report Template").Select
    If lastRow > 4 Then
        Range("A5:C" & lastRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Range("D4:P" & lastRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Range("Q5:S" & lastRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Else
    End If

    Call CopyResults

End Sub
Sub CopyResults()
    Dim A, B
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim srcRng, destRng As Range

    'Copy DP-CustomerDates
    Sheets("DP-CustomerDates").Select
    Range("A1:D" & lastRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    'Paste customer dates
    Sheets("CustomerDates").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Copy DP-FirstDeliveries
    Sheets("DP-FirstDeliveries").Select
    Range("A1:C" & lastRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    'Paste first deliveries
    Sheets("FirstDeliveries").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Set arrays for source and destination sheets
    A = Array("DP-SalesW1", "DP-SalesW2", "DP-SalesW3", "DP-SalesW4", "DP-SalesW5", "DP-SalesW6", "DP-SalesW7", _
     "DP-SalesW8", "DP-SalesW9", "DP-SalesW10", "DP-SalesW11", "DP-SalesW12", "DP-SalesW13", "DP-SalesW14", "DP-SalesW15")
    B = Array("SalesW1", "SalesW2", "SalesW3", "SalesW4", "SalesW5", "SalesW6", "SalesW7", "SalesW8", "SalesW9", _
     "SalesW10", "SalesW11", "SalesW12", "SalesW13", "SalesW14", "SalesW15")

    For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
        Set srcRng = Worksheets(A(i)).UsedRange
        srcRng.Copy
        Set destRng = Worksheets(B(i)).Range("A1")
        destRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next

    Call CustomerDates

End Sub
Sub CustomerDates()

    Worksheets("CustomerDates").Select

    'Set header for column E
    Range("E1").Formula = "Weeks"

    'Calculate number of weeks
    Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Formula = "=ROUNDDOWN((TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)-C2)/7,0)+1"

    'Set header for column F
    Range("F1").Formula = "New Customers"

    'If customer is less than 14 weeks copy the name for the template
    Range("F2:F" & lastRow) = Evaluate("IF(E2:E" & lastRow & " < 14,B2:B" & lastRow & ","""")")

    'Add Named Range
    'Sheets("FirstDeliveries").Select
    Columns("B:E").Select
    Range("E1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="CustomerDates", RefersToR1C1:="='CustomerDates'!C2:C5"

    Call FirstDeliveries
End Sub
Sub FirstDeliveries()

    Worksheets("FirstDeliveries").Select

    'Remove all but the first deliveries
    'Based on sort order
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C" & lastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    'Week ending calculation
    Range("D1").Formula = "Week Ending"
    Range("D2:D" & lastRow).Formula = "=B2-WEEKDAY(B2,2)+7"

    'Add Named Range
    Sheets("FirstDeliveries").Select
    Columns("A:D").Select
    Range("D1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="FirstDelivery", RefersToR1C1:="='FirstDeliveries'!C1:C4"


    Call SalesTotals
End Sub
Sub SalesTotals() 'Setup result sets with subtotals
    Dim ValueSh, salesSh As Worksheet

    'Subtotal sales
    For Each salesSh In Sheets(Array("SalesW1", "SalesW2", "SalesW3", "SalesW4", "SalesW5", "SalesW6", "SalesW7", _
     "SalesW8", "SalesW9", "SalesW10", "SalesW11", "SalesW12", "SalesW13", "SalesW14", "SalesW15"))
        salesSh.Select
        'Subtotal
        On Error Resume Next
        'Add column heading
        Range("AX1").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "Sales"
        'Sum each row and fill down
        Range("AX2").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(B2:AB2)-SUM(AC2:AW2)"
        Range("AX2:AX" & lastRow).FillDown
        'Remove formulas
        Range("AX2:AX" & lastRow).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        'Remove details
        Columns("B:AW").Select
        Selection.EntireColumn.Delete
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(2), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True

        'Remove subtotal formulas
        Range("B2:B" & lastRow + 1).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        'View Totals
        ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
        Range("A1").Select
        'Remove "Total"
        With Range("A:A")
            .Replace What:=" Total", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        End With
    Next
    Call DeleteHiddenRows

End Sub
Sub DeleteHiddenRows()

    Dim rngHidden As Range
    Dim Sh As Worksheet

    'Create the sheets array.
    For Each Sh In Sheets(Array("SalesW1", "SalesW2", "SalesW3", "SalesW4", "SalesW5", "SalesW6", "SalesW7", _
     "SalesW8", "SalesW9", "SalesW10", "SalesW11", "SalesW12", "SalesW13", "SalesW14", "SalesW15"))
        Sh.Select
        'Error handler for case: No hidden cells
        On Error Resume Next ' In case there's no hidden cells
        Range("A1").Select
        'Delete hidden cells
        With Cells
            Set rngHidden = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            .EntireRow.Hidden = False 'Unhide all cells
            rngHidden.EntireRow.Hidden = True 'Hide previously visible cells
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete 'Delete previously hidden cells
            rngHidden.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'Unhide previously visible cells
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.RemoveSubtotal
    Next

    'Add Named Range
    Sheets("SalesW1").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW1", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW1'!C1:C2"
    Sheets("SalesW2").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW2", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW2'!C1:C2"
    Sheets("SalesW3").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW3", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW3'!C1:C2"
    Sheets("SalesW4").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW4", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW4'!C1:C2"
    Sheets("SalesW5").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW5", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW5'!C1:C2"
    Sheets("SalesW6").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW6", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW6'!C1:C2"
    Sheets("SalesW7").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW7", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW7'!C1:C2"
    Sheets("SalesW8").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW8", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW8'!C1:C2"
    Sheets("SalesW9").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW9", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW9'!C1:C2"
    Sheets("SalesW10").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW10", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW10'!C1:C2"
    Sheets("SalesW11").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW11", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW11'!C1:C2"
    Sheets("SalesW12").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW12", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW12'!C1:C2"
    Sheets("SalesW13").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW13", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW13'!C1:C2"
    Sheets("SalesW14").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW14", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW14'!C1:C2"
    Sheets("SalesW15").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW15", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW15'!C1:C2"


    Call BuildCommissions
End Sub
Sub BuildCommissions()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lRow As Long

    'Select the sheet and set ws
    Worksheets("CustomerDates").Select
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'Find last row column F
    With ws
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    'Copy
    Range("F2:F" & lRow).Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Select template, paste values
    Worksheets("Commission Report Template").Select
    Range("B5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Find last row column B
    With ActiveSheet
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'Lookup first deliveries
    Range("A5:A" & lRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B5,FirstDelivery,4,FALSE)"
    'Remove formulas
    Range("A5:A" & lRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Add week ending dates
    Range("D4:P4").Formula = "=Parameters!B3"
    'Remove formulas
    Range("A5:A" & lRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    'Formats
    Range("D4:P4").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True

    'If start week is #N/A remove the row
    For i = 5 To Range("A" & "65536").End(xlUp).Row Step 1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A" & i), "#N/A") = 1 Then
            Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    'Find new last row
    With ActiveSheet
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'Add formulas for weekly sales
    Range("D5:D" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW1,2,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW1,2,FALSE))"
    Range("E5:E" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW2,2,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW2,2,FALSE))"
    Range("F5:F" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW3,2,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW3,2,FALSE))"
    Range("G5:G" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW4,2,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW4,2,FALSE))"
    Range("H5:H" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW5,2,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW5,2,FALSE))"
    Range("I5:I" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW6,2,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW6,2,FALSE))"
    Range("J5:J" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW7,2,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW7,2,FALSE))"
    Range("K5:K" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW8,2,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW8,2,FALSE))"
    Range("L5:L" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW9,2,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW9,2,FALSE))"
    Range("M5:M" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW10,2,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW10,2,FALSE))"
    Range("N5:N" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW11,2,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW11,2,FALSE))"
    Range("O5:O" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW12,2,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW12,2,FALSE))"
    Range("P5:P" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW13,2,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(B5,SalesW13,2,FALSE))"

    'Add formulas for averages and totals
    Range("Q5:Q" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(AVERAGE(B5:P5)),"""",AVERAGE(B5:P5))"
    Range("R5:R" & lRow).Formula = "=SUM(B5:P5)"
    Range("S5:S" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(B5,CustomerDates,3,FALSE)=0,""A"",""Q"")"

    'Remove formulas
    Range("D4:S" & lRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Remove $0 and not null cells
    Range("D5:P65536").Replace What:=0, LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:=""

    'Sort
    Range("A5:S" & lRow).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Commission Report Template").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Commission Report Template").Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("A5"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Commission Report Template").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A5:S" & lRow)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("A3").Select

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Unload UserForm1
    OutPut = MsgBox("Report completed successfully.", vbInformation, "Awesome!")

End Sub
Function lastRow()

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about [what your code does](//codereview.meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226) and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The current title states your concerns about the code; it needs an [edit] to simply *state the task*; see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: You should probably start by watching this video: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) and then continue watching the rest of the series.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to take a stab at some of the obvious as this is my first review here.

- **[How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)**

  Select and Active(Sheet/Workbook/etc) are very fickle instructions for VBA to understand. They will default to whatever workbook/sheet was last acted on, and as we all know from our debugging adventures, that can vary depending on the time of day and position of the moon.

  Instead of relying on something that changes, try creating and using variables to store locations/information/directions. One of the first things I always do is set the workbook and worksheet I'm working on. For a brief example:

  ```
  Dim wbSourceData as workbook, wsSalesData as worksheet
  Set wbSourceData = ThisWorkbook
  Set wsSalesData = wbSourceData.Sheets(1)
  ```

  Now the workbook that holds the macro and the sheet that holds your data are locked into that variable. You don't need to keep typing 'ActiveWorkbook' or 'ActiveWorksheet' over and over again to access your data. Setting workbooks and worksheets also greatly assist in referring to ranges and performing actions on data.
- **Making the most of your variables**

  Variables exist so that you don't have to retype the same things over and over again. I see that you have a few instances where you have essentially re-declared variables such as:

  ```
  'Remove previous results
  For Each ResultsSh In Sheets(Array("CustomerDates", "FirstDeliveries", "SalesW1", "SalesW2", _
   "SalesW3", "SalesW4", "SalesW5", "SalesW6", "SalesW7", "SalesW8", "SalesW9", "SalesW10", _
    "SalesW11", "SalesW12", "SalesW13", "SalesW14", "SalesW15"))
  ```

  And

  ```
  'Set arrays for source and destination sheets
  A = Array("DP-SalesW1", "DP-SalesW2", "DP-SalesW3", "DP-SalesW4", "DP-SalesW5", "DP-SalesW6", "DP-SalesW7", _
   "DP-SalesW8", "DP-SalesW9", "DP-SalesW10", "DP-SalesW11", "DP-SalesW12", "DP-SalesW13", "DP-SalesW14", "DP-SalesW15")
  B = Array("SalesW1", "SalesW2", "SalesW3", "SalesW4", "SalesW5", "SalesW6", "SalesW7", "SalesW8", "SalesW9", _
   "SalesW10", "SalesW11", "SalesW12", "SalesW13", "SalesW14", "SalesW15")
  ```

  I would recommend declaring these and then calling them to each sub so that you don't have to rewrite them. An example of how to call a variable to a sub is:

  ```
  Sub CopyResults(byref MyArray as variant)
  ```

  Further reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637449/excel-vba-passing-argument-parameter-to-sub), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722146/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-vba), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624279/vba-returning-error-when-calling-a-sub-with-multiple-parameters).
  By using those parenthesis at the sub declaration, you can pass variables across procedures and only declare them once. Saves quite a bit of typing.

  Another way to get the most out of your variables is to name them effectively. Instead of `A = Array(...)` try something like `SalesWSArray = Array(...)`. This wraps the fact that it is an array, it refers to the worksheets (WS), and it refers specifically to the Sales worksheets, all tied up in a nice variable.
- **Repeated code can usually be compressed**

  I see you have a long piece of code starting here:

  ```
  'Add Named Range
  Sheets("SalesW1").Select
  Columns("A:B").Select
  Range("B1").Activate
  ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SalesW1", RefersToR1C1:="='SalesW1'!C1:C2"
  Sheets("SalesW2").Select
  Columns("A:B").Select
  Range("B1").Activate
  'etc etc....
  ```

  You created a great array and loop but then didn't utilize it. If you see a piece of code that is doing the same thing over and over again, it can most likely be shoved into a function or a loop. Such as:

  ```
  For i = 1 to UBound(SalesWSArray)
      ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:= SalesWSArray(i), RefersToR1C1:="='" & SalesWSArray(i) & "'!C1:C2"
  Next i
  ```

  I assumed here that your worksheet array was 1D with a 0 base. By starting at i = 1, this loop will be able to hit the first worksheet in the array (`Sheets("SalesW1").Select`) and pull the data you need.
- **Procedural Organization**

  At then end of your subs you have `Call NamedSub`. I see that in most cases the called sub is the very next one. VBA is linear and will automatically flow down the written page unless you tell it otherwise. There is no need to call the next sub unless it is specifically out of order (such as the function you have at the very bottom of your code). Also you don't need to 'call' a sub. Simply reference it by name if it's in the same module, or by module.subname if it resides in a difference module:

  ```
  Sub TestRuns()
      SubSameModule anyVariablesYouAreReferencing
      Module2.SubDifferentModule anyVariablesYouAreReferencing
  End Sub
  ```
- **General Tips and Suggestions**

  I recommend hitting up StackOverflow and reading all the questions and answers you can. Sometimes things other people do are things you do, and you can get a good idea of VBA convention and best practice. Also read the reviews on here to get an idea of what developers expect and notice about VBA coding.

Please note none of these examples have been tested and please remember to save all your work before implementing anything.

Comment: Please consider pulling the key content out of links and into your answer itself, as links may rot.

Comment: @Dannnno right, good point. I have edited my list.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:= SalesWSArray(i), RefersToR1C1:="='" & SalesWSArray(i) & "'!C1:C2"` is the only line needed in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

#### Variable Declaration

Always turn on `Option Explicit`. You can have it automatically by going to Tools -> Options in the VBE and checking the **Require Variable Declaration** option. This way if you have any variables not defined, the compiler will let you know.

Your variable `outPut` isn't declared. When you don't define your variable, VBA will declare it as a *Variant*, which are [objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcxd6b8.aspx):

> Performance. A variable you declare with the Object type is flexible
>   enough to contain a reference to any object. However, when you invoke
>   a method or property on such a variable, you always incur late binding
>   (at run time). To force early binding (at compile time) and better
>   performance, declare the variable with a specific class name, or cast
>   it to the specific data type.

.

> ```
> Dim DataSh, ResultsSh As Worksheet
> ```

You don't realize it here, but you aren't giving `DataSh` a *type* -

```
Dim Datash as Worksheet, ResultsSh as Worksheet
```

Same goes for

> ```
> Dim A, B
> Dim srcRng
> Dim ValueSh
> ```

Once again, it's a variant.

> ```
>  Dim i As Integer
> ```

Integers - [integers are obsolete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520). According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164506(v=office.10).aspx) VBA *silently* converts all integers to `long`.

#### Variable Naming

Worksheets have a `CodeName` property - View Properties window (<kbd>F4</kbd>) and the `(Name)` field (the one at the top) can be used as the worksheet name. This way you can avoid `Sheets(""Commission Report Template"")` and instead just use `ReportTemplate`.

[Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other variables and names.

> ```
> Dim DataSh, ResultsSh As Worksheet
> Dim A, B
> Dim i As Integer
> Dim srcRng, destRng As Range
> Dim ValueSh, salesSh As Worksheet
> Dim rngHidden As Range
> Dim Sh As Worksheet
> Dim outPut
> ```

Give your variables meaningful names! Also, there's no need for that *hungarian naming*. I'm not going to get into Hungarian vs hungarian vs hungarian apps, but basically, the naming of your variables should tell me what it is, so don't prefix it with a type e.g.

- rngHidden - hiddenRange

Also, what's a `Sh`? I'd go with something like this -

```
Dim sourceData As Worksheet
Dim results As Worksheet
Dim arrayOfSheets As Variant 'A or B
Dim sheetNames As Variant    'A or B
Dim index As Long
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim destinationRange As Range
Dim valueSheet As Worksheet
Dim hiddenRange As Range
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim outPut As VbMsgBoxResult
```

#### Arrays

When you do something like this -

> ```
> A = Array("DP-SalesW1", "DP-SalesW2", "DP-SalesW3", "DP-SalesW4", "DP-SalesW5", "DP-SalesW6", "DP-SalesW7", _
>      "DP-SalesW8", "DP-SalesW9", "DP-SalesW10", "DP-SalesW11", "DP-SalesW12", "DP-SalesW13", "DP-SalesW14", "DP-SalesW15")
> ```

You could probably find a better way, even just as simple as

```
Const DP_SHEET_NAMES As String = "DP-SalesW1, DP-SalesW2, DP-SalesW3, DP-SalesW4, DP-SalesW5, DP-SalesW6, DP-SalesW7, DP-SalesW8, DP-SalesW9, DP-SalesW10, DP-SalesW11, DP-SalesW12, DP-SalesW13, DP-SalesW14, DP-SalesW15"
Const DELIMITER As String = ","
dpSheetsArray = Split(DP_SHEET_NAMES, DELIMITER)
```

Or

```
Dim sheetNames() As String
ReDim sheetNames(1 To 15)
Dim sheetNameIndex As Long
For sheetNameIndex = 1 To 15
    sheetNames(sheetNameIndex) = "DP - SalesW" & sheetNameIndex
Next
```

Or a combination

```
Const SHEET_PREFIX As String = "DP - SalesW"
Dim sheetNames() As String
ReDim sheetNames(1 To 15)
Dim sheetNameIndex As Long
For sheetNameIndex = 1 To 15
    sheetNames(sheetNameIndex) = SHEET_PREFIX & sheetNameIndex
Next
```

You see where I'm going. Constants are useful, as are loops.

#### Comments

Comments - ["code tell you how, comments tell you why"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/). The code should speak for itself, if it needs a comment, it might need to be made more clear. If not, the comment should describe *why* you're doing something rather than *how* you're doing it. Here are a [few reasons](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/254979/125931) to avoid comments all together.

You have a lot of comments, explaining what is happening. That's an indication that your code isn't clear enough.

> ```
> 'Remove previous template results
>  Worksheets(Commission Report Template).Select
>  If lastRow > 4 Then
>     Range(A5:C & lastRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
>     Range(D4:P & lastRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
>     Range(Q5:S & lastRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
>  Else
>  End If
> ```

Looks like you could probably use some *Named Ranges* in the sheet.

Instead of hard-coding names, if they are static, assign them a *named range* property. e.g. instead of `Sheets("mySheet").Range("A1:A10")` you can have `mysheet.Range("MyNamedRange")`.

#### .Select

It's been mentioned, but be sure to avoid things like `.Select` - it just slows the code down by needing to fiddle with the spreadsheet while doing everything else behind the scenes. There's a good question on StackOverflow [addressing this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

#### Call Sub

> ```
> Call CopyResults
> ```

Can just be

```
CopyResults
```

You don't need to `Call` subs, it's obsolete. Instead just use `Sub argument, argument`

#### Arrays

What you're suffering from is beginner's luck. I've been there, everyone has been there. How do we know what is better than doing what you're doing? Because we've done it and been told "hey, there's a better way!". So, don't get discouraged.

But, everything you're doing should be done in an array.

**For Example**-

> ```
> 'Copy DP-CustomerDates
>     Sheets(DP - CustomerDates).Select
>     Range(A1:D & lastRow).Select
>     Selection.Copy
>     'Paste customer dates
>     Sheets(CustomerDates).Select
>     Range(A1).Select
>     Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
> ```

Would be *much* faster as

```
Dim results As Variant
results = Sheets(DP - CustomerDates).Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 4))
Sheets("CustomerDates").Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 4)) = results
```

Copy and Pasting is *extremely* inefficient. Give using arrays a try!

#### Refactoring

You say

> I find there is a lot of redundant code which I think could be streamlined

That's called refactoring. Let's take the loop in `SalesTotals()` for a spin

```
For Each salesSh In Sheets(Array(SalesW1, SalesW2, SalesW3, SalesW4, SalesW5, SalesW6, SalesW7, _
     SalesW8, SalesW9, SalesW10, SalesW11, SalesW12, SalesW13, SalesW14, SalesW15))
        salesSh.Select
        'Subtotal
        On Error Resume Next
        'Add column heading
        Range(AX1).Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = Sales
        'Sum each row and fill down
        Range(AX2).Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = =SUM(B2:AB2)-SUM(AC2:AW2)
        Range(AX2:AX & lastRow).FillDown
        'Remove formulas
        Range(AX2:AX & lastRow).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        'Remove details
        Columns(B:AW).Select
        Selection.EntireColumn.Delete
        Range(A1).Select
        Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(2), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True

        'Remove subtotal formulas
        Range(B2:B & lastRow + 1).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        'View Totals
        ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
        Range(A1).Select
        'Remove Total
        With Range(A:A)
            .Replace What:= Total, Replacement:=, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        End With
    Next
```

First to note is that **all** of those `columns` `Range` and `ActiveCell` are *unqualified*. You need to explicitly state where they are (ignoring the `.Select` issue for now)

```
For index = LBound(salessheets) To UBound(salessheets)
    Set salessheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(salessheets(index))
    With salessheet
        .Range("AX1").Select
        .Selection.Copy
        '...
    End With
Next
```

Right, now we know where the range is, explicitly. As far as refactoring it, it could become

```
Dim index As Long
For index = LBound(salessheets) To UBound(salessheets)
    Set salessheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(salessheets(index))
    ClearTotals salessheet
Next
```

with

```
Private Sub ClearTotals(ByVal targetSheet As Worksheet)
     With targetSheet
            'Subtotal
            On Error Resume Next
            'Add column heading
            Range(AX1).Select
            ActiveCell.Formula = Sales
            'Sum each row and fill down
            Range(AX2).Select
            .ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(B2:AB2)-SUM(AC2:AW2)"
            .Range("AX2:AX" & lastRow).FillDown
            'Remove formulas
            .Range("AX2:AX" & lastRow).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            'Remove details
            .Columns("B:AW").Select
            Selection.EntireColumn.Delete
            Range(A1).Select
            Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(2), _
            Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
            'Remove subtotal formulas
            .Range("B2:B" & lastRow + 1).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            'View Totals
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
            Range("A1").Select
            'Remove Total
            With .Columns("A").Replace(What:="Total", Replacement:="Something", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False)
            End With
        End With
End Sub
```

That's refactoring, for instance. But you still have the issue of `.Select` and everything else.

An example of that refactored sub might be

```
 With targetSheet
        Dim newValues As Variant
        Dim oldValues As Variant
        Dim index As Long
        Dim sumIndex As Long

        Dim firstValue As Long
        Dim secondValue As Long
        oldValues = targetSheet.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(49, lastRow))
        ReDim newValues(1 To lastRow - 1)
        For index = 1 To UBound(newValues)
            For sumIndex = 1 To 28
                firstValue = firstValue + oldValues(index, sumIndex)
            Next
            For sumIndex = 29 To 49
                secondValue = secondValue + oldValues(index, sumIndex)
            Next
            newValues(index) = firstValue - secondValue
        Next
        targetSheet.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, UBound(newValues))) = newValues
End With
```

I can't guarantee that's exactly what you're trying to do, but it's a start.

Heck (and I'm spit-balling here), I'd even say you could do something like

```
   For index = LBound(salessheets) To UBound(salessheets)
        Dim tempArray as Variant
        Set salessheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(salessheets(index))
        tempArray = GetSums(salesSheet)
        salseSheet.Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(1,Ubound(tempArray)) = tempArray
    Next

Private Function GetSums(ByVal TargetSheet as Worksheet) as Variant
    'Do the stuff
    ' GetSums = newValues
End Function
```

---

### Without Test Data

Here's an example of how I might approach the first two procedures of yours

```
Sub RefreshData()
    Const DATA_SHEETS As String = "DP-CustomerDates, DP-FirstDeliveries, DP-SalesW1, DP-SalesW2, DP-SalesW3, DP-SalesW4, DP-SalesW5, DP-SalesW6, DP-SalesW7, DP-SalesW8, DP-SalesW9, DP-SalesW10, DP-SalesW11, DP-SalesW12, DP-SalesW13, DP-SalesW14, DP-SalesW15"
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sheetNames As Variant
    sheetNames = Split(DATA_SHEETS, ",")
    Dim index As Long
    Dim targetListObject As ListObject
    Dim resultSheet As Worksheet

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With


    For index = LBound(sheetNames) To UBound(sheetNames)
        Set dataSheet = Sheets(sheetNames(index))
        With dataSheet
            Set targetListObject = .ListObjects(1)
            targetListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
            targetListObject.QueryTable.Refresh False
            .Rows.Hidden = False
            .Columns("A:AX").Delete shift:=xlToLeft
        End With
    Next

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Set dataSheet = Worksheets("Commission Report Template")
    With dataSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow > 4 Then
            .Range("A5:C" & lastRow).Delete shift:=xlUp
            .Range("D4:P" & lastRow).Delete shift:=xlUp
            .Range("Q5:S" & lastRow).Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
    End With
    CopyResults sheetNames
End Sub

Sub CopyResults(ByVal sourceSheetNames As Variant)
    Const TARGET_SHEET_NAMES As String = "SalesW1, SalesW2, SalesW3, SalesW4, SalesW5, SalesW6, SalesW7, SalesW8, SalesW9,SalesW10, SalesW11, SalesW12, SalesW13, SalesW14, SalesW15"
    Dim targetSheetNames As Variant
    targetSheetNames = Split(TARGET_SHEET_NAMES, ",")
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim firstVariant As Variant
    Dim index As Long
    Set dataSheet = Sheets(sourceSheetNames(1))
    firstVariant = GetArray(dataSheet, 4)
    Sheets("CustomerDates").Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(firstarray), 4)) = firstVariant
    Set dataSheet = Sheets(sourceSheetNames(2))
    firstVariant = GetArray(dataSheet, 3)
    Sheets(FirstDeliveries).Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(firstarray), 3)) = firstVariant

    For index = 3 To UBound(sourceSheetNames)
        Set dataSheet = Sheets(sourceSheetNames(index))
        Set targetSheet = Sheets(targetSheetNames(index - 2))
        lastRow = dataSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastColumn = dataSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        targetSheet.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)) = dataSheet.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
    Next

    CustomerDates

End Sub
```